# Is a graph database the right way to represent hierarchical electric power distribution?

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, arangodb, amazon-neptune, flockdb

I have a time series database that takes in power meter data for a campus.  Using this data has been a challenge, in part because the power distribution is a hierarchy.  There are some cases where if you want to know how much power building X is using, you just read that meter.  There are other cases where building X also feeds building Y, so to know what X is consuming you have to read meter X then subtract Y.  There are multiple circuits in some buildings and they all feed each other in ways you can understand by looking at the system diagram, but from a data analysis perspective it's hard to know that when I read this meter I have to understand things about all the other meters underneath it.

In some cases, you also have to worry about the meter next to it.  For example, some buildings have a transformer that steps 12.47KV down to 480V then steps down to 208V from there.  In other buildings, there are 480V and 208V transformers side by side, and to know the total building consumption you have to add them together.

I know a lot about RDBMS and TSDB but very little about graph databases.  I've done a bunch of reading about graph databases, and I'm wondering if this looks like a useful way to represent the distribution hierarchy, with the sole purpose of you query this graphdb to learn the rules you have to use when analyzing data from the TSDB.  Being completely new to graph databases I'm wondering: does this make sense, or is that graphdb abuse and I really just need to store trees?

Answer (score 1):

One strength of a graph database is treating relationships as the first-class elements of your data model. The other is the ability to scale, particularly if you need to go over a number of relationships to find answers.

In your case, the relationships among buildings, circuits, transformers, and meters are as meaningful, if not more, as the numbers on the meters. It seems more helpful to map your data model in a directed property graph to simplify and codify your situation.

You seemed to have already explored a couple of native graph databases as well as multi-modal ones. May I dare to invite you to give NebulaGraph, an open-source distributed graph native database, a try?

Comment: I will give it a look.  Thank you for articulating those two strengths.  That really helps.  That is indeed the case - the relationships are as important as the data, because without knowing the relationships, the data does not have meaning!